# how can store executed statement (not fetched from a table) in a variable or table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Dear Friends I want to store executed statement's value into a variable or table but right now  I am stuck and not able to get the solution, hoping I will get solution here.

my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_grants`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_grants`(_user VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT(1) DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE _grant TEXT DEFAULT '';

        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('\'', USER ,'\'@\'', HOST,'\'') FROM mysql.user WHERE USER=_user;


        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
-- open cursor1
OPEN cur1;
BEGIN
REPEAT
FETCH cur1 INTO _grant;

IF _grant='' THEN
    SET done = 1;
END IF; 

            IF (done<>1) THEN
    SET @str1=CONCAT('show grants for ',_grant);
                 PREPARE stmt1 FROM @str1;
                 EXECUTE stmt1;
                 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

            END IF;

UNTIL done
END REPEAT;
END;
     CLOSE cur1;
-- close cursor1     

     SELECT 'done';

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Getting below results

CALL sp_grants('zafar');

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'zafar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*20F283F208C26099783173695D6F7BBF24E2346B';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test`.* TO 'zafar'@'%'
```

I want to store above 2 rows in a variable or table.

Please help me, i will be very thankful.

Note: I know if i was preparing statements from any table data then i can store these statements col1 into @var1 but how can I do here.

Comment: You can't. You have to write a proper select gathering information from the mysql database (yes, there's a database in mysql called mysql).

Comment: One option is to use the framework [`common_schema`](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html) and specifically the view [`sql_show_grants`](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/sql_show_grants.html).